# Jtable plugin for sorting and filtering html table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-jtable

I want to user Jtable plugin for sorting,paging  my html table in my project, when i visited the official site of the Jtable plugin , there is nothing called buy but there is something called donate on the site, is this Jtable plugin free??

As i dont want to have any issues in the future, can we use it freely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the about page you can read, "jTable is developed by Halil İbrahim Kalkan and licensed under [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)."

The MIT License is a free software license originating at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT). It is a permissive free software license, meaning that it permits reuse within proprietary software provided all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms. Such proprietary software retains its proprietary nature even though it incorporates software under the MIT License. The license is also GPL-compatible, meaning that the GPL permits combination and redistribution with software that uses the MIT License.